# How to avoid unique key violation while saving entities with one to many relationship using spring data and jpa hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, one-to-many, put

I have a problem while saving two entities that have "one to many" relationship. I get the ConstraintViolationException:

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint '...'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.classification'. The duplicate key value is (...).

Here are my entities:

```
@Data
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"x", "y"})
})
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Account {

    @Id
    @Nullable
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    
    @Nonnull
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "accountId")
    private Set<Classification> classifications = new HashSet<>();

    
    ... rest fields

}

@Data
@Table(uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"accountId", "anotherClassification"})
})
@Entity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Classification {

    @Id
    @Nullable
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Nonnull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer accountId;

    @Nonnull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AnotherClassification anotherClassification;
}
```

Now on the frontend I edit classifications and e.g delete one entry, so in the request I have an account with a set of classifications which (of course) are already stored in the database. The exception occurres because it cannot be added again.
This is the service method which is called by @PutMapping within the AccountController:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public Account updateAccount(Integer id, AccountRequest accountRequest) {
    return accountRepository.findById(id).map(account -> {
        ...
        Set<Classification> classifications = new HashSet<>();
        List<AnotherClassification> requestClassifications = accountRequest.getClassifications();
        requestClassifications.forEach(ac -> {
            Classification classification = new Classification(account.getId(), ac);
            classifications.add(classification);
        });
        account.setClassifications(classifications);
        return accountRepository.save(account);
    }).orElseThrow(() -> idAccountNotFoundException(id));
}
```

I tried also to build manual cleaning of classifications (like below) and call it at the beginning of update method, but it did not help.
Entries are not deleted and still the same error.

```
@Override
public void clearClassificationsForAccount(Integer accountId) {
    classificationRepo.deleteAllByAccountId(accountId);
    classificationRepo.flush();
}
```

What is the proper way to do such an update?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you map classification as entity? You could just use an element collection mapping like this:

```
@Nonnull
@ElementCollection
@Column(nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Set<AnotherClassification> classifications = new HashSet<>();
```

This will create a table with just two columns i.e. the ones that you are using for the unique constraint. If you really must use a surrogate id, you could try to implement equals-hashCode based on your natural id i.e. the fields `accountId` and `anotherClassification`.

Comment: I use EqualsAndHashcode from lombok, I thought it is enough. Well I would prefer to use regular OneToMany relation, if possible. Why it is not just updated?

Comment: There are so many possible reasons for this. If you think this is a bug, please create an issue in the issue tracker(https://hibernate.atlassian.net) with a test case(https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates/blob/master/orm/hibernate-orm-5/src/test/java/org/hibernate/bugs/JPAUnitTestCase.java) that reproduces the issue.